# Swift 2 - UITableView with Multi sections

Tags: swift

I created a table with three sections, each section should handle an Animal array

var firstAnimals = Animal
var secondAnimals = Animal and so on

I am having trouble in the cellForRowAtIndexPath function, I want it to insert the items of the arrays according to the right section.  I tried this, but it doesn't work with the array.  Please help!

```
   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell
    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.title.text = firstAnimals[indexPath.row]

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.title.text = secondAnimals[indexPath.row]

    } else {
        cell.title.text = thirdAnimals[indexPath.row]
    }


    return cell
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work with the array"? As the code is now, I don't see the array anywhere.

Comment: @yesthisisjoe hey I fixed it, please help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended way is to use a nested array

```
let animals = [[firstAnimal1, firstAnimal2, firstAnimal3],
               [secondAnimal1, secondAnimal2, secondAnimal3],
               [thirdAnimal1, thirdAnimal2, thirdAnimal3]]
```

Then `cellForRowAtIndexPath` could look like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myCell
    let animalSection = animals[indexPath.section]
    let animal = animalSection[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = animal.name

    return cell
}
```

Alternatively use an array with the section names and a dictionary with an animal array for each section name respectively. The section name array can also be used as the section header names.

Comment: This is a good idea, @vadian, one thing, is there a way I can do something like this: let animals = [[firstAnimal],[secondAnimal],[thirdAnimal]], I mean pass array, Xcode won't let me do it.  Do you know a walk around?

Comment: Of course you can do that, but what's the purpose of an array containing only one object?

Comment: No I mean pass arrays, sorry, like this: let animals = [firstAnimals,secondAnimals,thnrdaanimals] How can I do it?

Comment: One array is one section. Multiple sections require a nested structure.